# how can I identify the format of a string to be used with DateTime?

Tags: c#

I have a database script that returns date time string and my problem is that I don't know what format my string will be.  The reason is that I have desktop in different culture and  they could return any kind of format.  My ultimate goal is, from the string to return the DateTime.
As I am trying to write something I am realizing that I would need to try any kind of format to make sure something comes back to me without an exception.
There should be a better way to do this without trial and error.
This is what I have but it only works for a few formats:

```
    public static DateTime FromQueryResultString(string dttmString)
    {
        string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", "dd.MM.yy hh:mm", "M/d/yy h:mm tt", "ddd MMM dd H:mm:ss yyyy", "dd.MM.yy hh:mm", "dd.MM.yy HH:mm","ddd MMM yy H:mm:ss yyyy" };

        string name = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        IFormatProvider format = new CultureInfo(name, false);
        DateTime formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dttmString, formats, format, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }
```

Comment: question .. start from the end and work backwards.. what date formats are you seeing.. and from there you could use the string.Format("mm/dd/yyyy",someDate) basically what I am asking is do you want all dates to share the same format end the end no matter what the input date format maybe..?

Comment: Can you change the "database script" to return a DateTime?

Comment: Any chance you could change the script to return the database `datetime` type instead?

Comment: isn't Database DateTime usually stored as a TimeStamp..? just wondering if that's the case..

Comment: The query is run by different desktop in different countries ,so I never know what culture the developer has set his desktop to. I have tested the query and it could return some interesting values.  I have listed some of them in my code (in the message) but there could be more.

Comment: >> Can you change the "database script" to return a DateTime? 
Not really. These are predefined queries. 
>> start from the end and work backwards.. 
That is what I have been doing and the list up there is the result. But it is not a good way because I would have to test on many more desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a fundamental concept.

Considering that you're talking about a DataBase script, it' a script, I immagine, which returns a data from *database*. Your database has to **always** hold a DateTime, floating point numbers and other culture sencitive data in *one common format*.  In this case, you will have one single stable Data Access Layer which will recover and manipulates data recovered from Rome, Paris, Beijing or Abu Dhabi. The *client* program that data will *visualize* in  culture dependent way.

In short: choose one format and store it in that way.

It's clear that this architecture is not *always* possible to have, but from my expirience it is possible in 99% of cases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear but I don't access the database directly.  I just run a command line offered to me and the results are in a text file. The database in question is Rational Synergy and the query is:
ccm query -format ">>>%objectname >>>%release >>>%create_time >>>%status >>>%purpose"
%create_time is what I need to translate

Comment: And there is no any way that you can query for DB culture?

Comment: I finally found a way to force a format that returns from the query so that I don't have to worry about the culture of the machine that is running the query.  It is a work around but it is a valid solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DateTime parsedDate;

if(DateTime.TryParse(dttmString, parsedDate)) 
{ 
      //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current culture set up via the [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx). Then you can get the date time format from the CultureInfo return object's Property DateTimeFormat. This means that Windows handles it and you do not have to do any special manual handling.

EDIT: Sample Code

```
public static DateTime FromQueryResultString(string dttmString) 
{ 
    string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    IFormatProvider format = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
    DateTime formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dttmString, formats, format, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

Comment: If I understand your point, are you suggesting to force a DateTime Format for my query so that it returns something I know?  I can't do that.  I can't decide the format of what the database is returning.

Comment: If I didn't understand your point, could you clarify? Maybe with an example. Thanks!

Comment: My point is the code that you have is not an issue. You should use the DateTimeFormat from the CurrentCulture info. The data store in the DB by the same user should be the same as the UI. If you can control the format then make to save the data the same way. I'll provide sample code too.

Comment: The database in question is Rational Synergy and the query is: ccm query -format ">>>%objectname >>>%release >>>%create_time >>>%status >>>%purpose" %create_time is what I need to translate

Comment: And there is no documentation on the format? Also I just posted the edited code. I have not tested but this should work from my understanding.